# Why does treating the index as a continuous variable not work when performing an inverse discrete Fourier transform?

Tags: matlab, fft, interpolation

I have a set of points describing a closed curve in the complex plane, call it `Z = [z_1, ..., z_N]`. I'd like to interpolate this curve, and since it's periodic, trigonometric interpolation seemed a natural choice (especially because of its increased accuracy). By performing the FFT, we obtain the Fourier coefficients:

```
F = fft(Z);
```

At this point, we could get `Z` back by the formula (where `1i` is the imaginary unit, and we use `(k-1)*(n-1)` because MATLAB indexing starts at 1)

```
                 N
   Z(n) = (1/N) sum  F(k)*exp( 1i*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), 1 <= n <= N.
                k=1
```

**My question**

Is there any reason why `n` must be an integer? Presumably, if we treat `n` as any real number between 1 and N, we will just get more points on the interpolated curve. **Is this true?** For example, if we wanted to double the number of points, could we not set

```
                 N
   Z_new(n) =  (1/N) sum  F(k)*exp( 1i*2*pi*(k-1)*(n-1)/N), with n = 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ..., N-1, N-0.5, N
                k=1
```

?

The new points are of course just subject to some interpolation error, but they'll be fairly accurate, right? **The reason I'm asking this question is because this method is not working for me. When I try to do this, I get a garbled mess of points that makes no sense.**

---

(By the way, I know that I could use the `interpft()` command, but I'd like to add points only in certain areas of the curve, for example between `z_a` and `z_b`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is when `n` is integer, you have some primary functions which are orthogonal and can be as a basis for the space. When, `n` is not integer, The exponential functions in the formula, are not orthogonal. Hence, the expression of a function based on these non-orthogonal basis is not meaningful as much as you expected.

For orthogonality case you can see the following as an example (from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform)). As you can check, you can find two `n_1` and `n_2` which are not integer, the following integrals are not zero any more, and they are not orthogonal.

[image]

Comment: Oh this is a nice answer. Thanks so much! (I know follow-up questions are sometimes annoying, but,) could you suggest a way to add points like I'm trying to do here in a way that actually works?

Comment: The answer is yes, you can add points and essentially interpolate at those discrete frequencies.  Check out the `czt` function if you have nodes that can be written in that form (that is, uniformly spaced in some manner).  Otherwise, what you're looking for is probably a non-uniform FFT.